# typedef redefinition with different types ('struct word' vs 'struct word') };

Tags: c

I am having difficulties with this one assignment and I keep getting an error whenever I am creating a linked list with other structures.

LinkedList.c

```
#include "sentence.c"

typedef struct{
    sentence *first;
    int numSentences;
}LinkedList;
```

Sentence.c

```
#include "word.c"

typedef struct{
  word *sentence;
  int lineNumber;
  int numWords;
}sentence;
```

Word.c

```
typedef struct{
  char *word;
  int numCharacters;
  int wordPos;
}word;
```

I am having problems only when I implement the linked list part, when I compile with the sentence and word structures they work fine.  I am not initializing the linked list anywhere and it is still giving this error for both sentence and word:

[image]

I am not really sure what this error means since I don't believe I am redeclaring it anywhere else.

Comment: unable to reproduce: https://repl.it/@WilliamLynch1/SlushyWatchfulInterchangeability.

Comment: You shouldn't be #including ".c" files. #including is only for ".h" files. But that's most likely not the cause of the error, though it will simplify troubleshooting. Most likely you are including word.c in 2 other files - either directly or indirectly.

Comment: Add your code to `.h` files (for convention) and put them in a [header guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to ensure that they are not included multiple times.

Comment: None of the types you show is `struct sentence` (you have no tag on any of the structures, although one of the tag-less (anonymous) structures is given a typedef name of `sentence`.  The error doesn't seem to correspond to the code you show.

Comment: OT:  most debuggers cannot show the fields within a struct unless the struct has a 'tag' name

Comment: regarding struct definitions like; `typedef struct{
  word *sentence;
  int lineNumber;
  int numWords;
}sentence;`  this has `sentence` as both the typedef name AND the name of a field within the same struct.  A modern compiler can handle such multiple naming, but it will confuse humans.

Comment: @user93353 Can you make your comment an answer so that I can mark it as the answer?  The problem was that I was using word.c in sentence and functions.c (another file of mine where I need access to it)

Comment: @StuartFong - done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be #including ".c" files. #include is only for ".h" files.

But that's most likely not the main cause of the error, though not doing it will simplify troubleshooting.

**Most likely you are including word.c in 2 other files - either directly or indirectly**

You should also make it a practice to add include guards for header files so as to fix multiple includes of the same header.

Answer (score 0):

- Never #include .c files, ever. No exceptions.
- Place typedefs that need to be accessed by other files in a .h file, such as word.h or sentence.h.
- It's not a brilliant idea to give a struct member the same identifier as the type of the struct where it resides.